# What is/are the most important thing(s) you wish that you have known/done before considering to apply to a PhD

Tags: phd

I wonder what your thoughts are on the above subject

Answer (score 2):

1) To know how bad/abusive/ morally evil/sexist supervisors/academics can be (and academia in general).

2) To know other (ex-)students from the target institution and talk to them. This really helps!

3) To know how unimportant good schools/doing much work is compared to things like family, friends, health etc. Indeed, I've often wished to have done less work during the PHD and to have spend more time with friends and hobbies.

I hope this helps, maybe more later!!!!

Comment: As an academic advising students, I agree with the above points.  I would also add that how 'unimportant good schools' is as compared to a good supervisor.  You can be at a top school but crap supervisor, and as a result, you will not likely to graduate, which amounts to nothing.  Also, I have students who joined a top colleague based on his/her research prowess, but little do they know he/she is a slave driver that demands results that only the top 0.01% of students are able to achieve.  So many of his/her students suffer mentally -- so point 2) is really important.